# Extract multiple indices values to the Feature collection in Google Earth Engine and export it as CSV File

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
var data= L8TOA1.filterDate('2019-02-01', '2019-03-28') 
             .filter(ee.Filter.equals('WRS_PATH', 146))
             .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 40))
             .sort('CLOUD_COVER').first();
print(data);
//Get cloud cover information
var cloud= data.get('CLOUD_COVER');
print('cloud_cover is',cloud);
//Cip with boundary
var Study_region = data.clipToCollection(aoi);
//Indice
var NDBI = ee.Image (Study_region.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B5']).rename('NDBI'));
var NDVI = ee.Image (Study_region.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'));
var SI= NDBI.addBands(NDVI)
print("Stacked_Image",SI);
var feature = ee.FeatureCollection([(Urban),(Vegetation)]);
print("Feature_points",feature);
//Extract values to the multiple points in different features
var img = SI.select(['NDBI','NDVI'])
 .reduceRegions({
   collection: feature,
   reducer: ee.Reducer.toList()});
print("Feature properties",img);
Export.table.toDrive({
   collection: img,
   description :"Indcies",
   folder:"GEE",
   fileNamePrefix: "Indcies_multifeature",
   fileFormat:"CSV",
});
```

I want to extract the values of NDVI and NDBI for multiple points in different featurecollection classes like Urban and Vegetation and export in different rows and columns. From the above code, the urban and vegetation are exported as 2 features(2 rows) and indices value of each point in the feature are exported together.

Answer (score 0):

Please, include a link to a working script and share all used assets. It makes it easier to help you.

You have an error in your script when clipping `data`. You probably want to call `data.clip(aoi)` instead of `data.clipToCollection(aoi)`. `data.clipToCollection()` expects an `ee.FeatureCollection` argument.

You also need to provide a scale when reducing regions:

```
var img = SI.select(['NDBI','NDVI'])
 .reduceRegions({
   collection: feature,
   reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
   scale: 30
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/85651439d2e7da0548d2c48092556200